# Java: How do I create a ReST service and call a URL

Tags: java, rest

Can anyone help me find a good tutorial for creating a ReST client in Java that would be able to call a URL.

I need a really basic tutorial that tells me where to find the API, how to import the jars, etc.

Edit: I tried Restlet, but the documentation was difficult to follow.

Thanks,
E

Comment: Why the downvotes? Downvotes without comment aren't helpful at all.

Comment: 2 down votes and no comment, not very helpful

Comment: Questions asked without even the slightest research are not helpful and get closed.

Comment: I edited my question a little bit.

Comment: @bmargulies, how would someone who is truly a beginner with web services be able to tell the difference between a good tutorial and a bad one?  There's plenty of crap out there...asking for a good starting point is not a bad question.  I've seen SO becoming less helpful and more pedantic recently...it's very sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been my experience that [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) is very easy to use.  This tutorial ([REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html)) is straightforward.

Comment: THat's the link I found yesterday. Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking HTTP here, so you'd likely find a good start just heading over the Apache and their [HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/) libraries. That should keep you in trouble for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Jersey Client. You can find many tutorials through google, but this should get you started with some good examples: http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html